# What is the policy concerning external deb-packages?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/30468/revisions) a deb-package was linked without any hint to the potential danger of bypassing Ubuntu's package management. I know that in the Window's world setup.exe are quite common, but common does not mean secure and also does not mean advisable.

So I was wondering:

- Should we never link to external deb-packages?
- Should we only use packages from trusted sources? What are trusted sources?
- Should we add them but always add a "be careful what you download"-hint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JRG has asked a question you can link to, now you can do this:

- If you see a question referencing a random .deb from the internets, edit it and add this notice:

  > **Note**: Installing packages from untrusted sources [**may harm your computer**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97667/what-precautions-should-i-take-with-debs-i-find-on-the-internet). Please consider finding an alternative, trusted source if you have to install this package.
- If you know of one, definitely add a comment pointing to a *more trusted* source, such as an officially endorsed PPA (by the vendor) or the Ubuntu repositories themselves.
- If you're sure your new source doesn't harm the quality of the answer, replace it altogether rather than adding a notice.

---

Please remember, this is only an "official policy" if you actually start doing it. Until then, I merely post this for the purpose of discussion.

But I'm championing this solution. Even though a couple of users will get disgruntled at the suggestion that their package is 'harmful', in the long term it'll help keep Ubuntu secure.

Comment: @k0pernikus Oops. Sorry. I just saw this on meta and went for it. :P

Answer (score 7):

We don't (yet) have a real policy concerning this. If you see a link to a .deb package and the same version of the same program is available from the repositories, you can of course edit the answer.

The german Ubuntu wiki - for instance - adds this notice whenever they use a standalone .deb:

> Notice
>
> [External packages](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/fremdquellen&ei=TTwcT_HyIcyd-wbfhMn0CQ&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCYQ7gEwAA&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dhttp://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Fremdquellen%26hl%3Den%26biw%3D1280%26bih%3D714%26prmd%3Dimvns) may harm your system

If you want to add this notice to an answer, you can do so. But you should find a better link than this google-translated page explaining why.

Chrome also warns you if you're trying to download a .deb:

[image]

I suggest you ask a question like "How can external packages harm my system?" and link to that, once it has an answer. Then you can add this notice every time you see a link to a deb and it will make sense to the user (who potentially has no choice but to download and install it in order to fix their problem).

Comment: Can I suggest this become our policy? Can we have a question on "safe strange .deb practice" or something, like we have PPA warning signs?