# Are software-recommendation questions for browser plugins on-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

Are questions asking how to do something in a web browser, which either implicitly or explicitly must be accomplished by a plugin, considered on-topic? That is, should we accept questions like this?

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/16062/how-to-display-currency-in-inr-directly-in-sites-like-ebay

My inclination is to say that this is on-topic, since such a plugin is software running on Ubuntu, we [support third party applications](https://askubuntu.com/faq#questions) anyway (so why not third party plugins?), and **there are substantial differences in what plugins are available and how well they work, from platform to platform**.

But I'm interested in seeing what the community thinks, as it's been suggested that this question should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: 1.) The currency conversion link didn't work for me. I got a "Page Not Found"? 2.) And not to split hairs, do you mean `add-ons` instead of `plug-ins`? I'm asking because, at least for Firefox, `about:addons` has plug-ins and extensions listed separately giving the impression that plug-ins and extensions are subsets of add-ons. 3.) I have the impression that more add-ons are OS-agnostic than not if we exclude certain proprietary ones.

Comment: @vasa1 (1) Yes, after it was closed as off-topic, the question was deleted. If you can find other good examples of this, please provide them. Otherwise, only 10k users will be able to see it (unless it's undeleted). I can quote from it if you think it'll really help. (2) To split hairs further, I didn't say "plug-ins." I said "plugins." :) On a more serious note: Different browsers use terms differently, but I am asking a browser-agnostic question; there is no reason for me to try to emulate the way the words are used in a particular browser.

Comment: @vasa1 (3) Can you expand on that? What does that mean for how we should deal with this issue? We answer platform-agnostic questions all the time; for example, Firefox and LibreOffice work mostly the same in Ubuntu and Windows but no one seems to think questions about them that also apply to Windows are off-topic. You may want to post an answer.

Comment: No, it's just a comment that because browsers mostly play the same way across platforms. I was hoping to get you to elaborate on "there are substantial differences in what plugins are available" because such instances would be clearly be "on-topic". And since you feel that plugins are different from plug-ins, perhaps that bears elaboration as well.

Comment: My preference is to ask a program-specific question in a venue dedicated to that program first and then if I'm pointed to an OS-specific aspect, I'd ask my question here, for example. But that depends on person to person. Others may feel more comfortable in an all-under-one-roof situation and shouldn't be asked to go elsewhere.

Comment: Q has been undeleted to allow a wider audience to see what this meta is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the answer is **NO** but I totally understand your inclination to say yes.

I guess there is a broader question "What is the definition of Third party Software as it relates to Ubuntu?  This may provoke differing opinions but my understanding is defined in [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2023/is-it-good-practice-to-recommend-users-install-software-from-third-party-app-sto) and there is a possibility that we need clearer guidelines on TPS.

When I looked at the example you used I initially thought yes this is on-topic as the OP is using Ubuntu, but then I asked myself, if I was was googling this query would AU be my first port of call to find the answer?  I think the answer to this is no.  Therefore the question maybe considered too localized as it will not benefit others.

That said, I can be swayed by the thoughts and opinions of others and I am eager to know also what everyone else thinks.