# Is it on-topic to ask about plugins in a browser?

Tags: discussion, scope, third-party-software

I was just wondering, is it on-topic here to ask about plugins in a browser, when the browser is running on Ubuntu, but the plugin is browser and not OS specific?

Comment: Probably, but [su] might be a better place.

Comment: I'd say yes - http://askubuntu.com/questions/624153/how-can-i-detach-a-tab-from-my-main-chrome-window-into-a-new-window happened to have a plugin as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most such questions are on-topic.

Plugins aren't the only aspect of web browser usage that may apply across different platforms, and web browsers are far from the only Ubuntu software that exists on other operating systems. In general, we allow questions about software that runs on Ubuntu and other OSes too--so long as the user asking the question is using it on Ubuntu.

We have a number of meta posts on the topic of non-Ubuntu-specific questions. Here are a few:

- [Are "not only Ubuntu-specific" questions on-topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14523/are-not-only-ubuntu-specific-questions-on-topic)
- [Are non-Ubuntu-spefic questions allowed?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14663/are-non-ubuntu-spefic-questions-allowed)
- [How do we tell if a question belongs here, or rather at stackoverflow/superuser?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/47/how-do-we-tell-if-a-question-belongs-here-or-rather-at-stackoverflow-superuser)
- [Unix vs Ubuntu?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15559/unix-vs-ubuntu)
- [Why are questions about packages included in Ubuntu by default but not maintained by Canonical not considered off-topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17174/why-are-questions-about-packages-included-in-ubuntu-by-default-but-not-maintaine)
- [Are bash/shell scripting questions on topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic)

So I presume questions about browser plugins are not, in general, off-topic. However:

- There does seem to be [something of a consensus](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3918/are-software-recommendation-questions-for-browser-plugins-on-topic) that browser plugin *recommendation* requests are off-topic. I'm not really sure how broadly we interpret this. If someone asks if the Chromium browser can display pages in a "reader" mode similar to that provided by Firefox, do we keep that question open and recommend an extension, or do we close it as off-topic? I hope we keep it open--and this ambiguity is why I oppose the current consensus on this--but I don't know what the community would decide.
- Some questions that seem to be about browser plugins might actually be about the more general topic of doing whatever task they help perform. For example, we would probably close questions asking for the best syntax to find PDF files with Google *using a Google search plugin*. We would definitely close questions asking for strategic advice for playing chess *with a chess-playing browser plugin*. And when a plugin is facilitating or taking the place of a webapp--for example, by enhancing a web-based interface to some service--I expect we would consider many questions about using it off-topic.

Even though I think most of these questions are on-topic, I agree [with muru](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14273/is-it-on-topic-to-ask-about-plugins-in-a-browser#comment24927_14273) that [Super User](https://superuser.com/) may be a better place for some of them. That's [up to the asker](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14530/22949), though.

Ultimately, I don't think we really get that many of these questions. You asked this two years ago and it has hardly been visited since. We may not need an established consensus on this. If we ever see an upswing in browser plugin questions, then either everybody will be fine with it and it will be implicitly on topic, or question will start getting closed and someone will ask on meta, and then it can be figured out.