# How to stop a mod from tagging a question as related to unsupported version when the question is not version specific?

Tags: discussion

How can I stop a mod from tagging a question as related to an unsupported version when the question is not version specific?

This is a very generic question that applies to probably every Ubuntu version that uses Apt. How can I get this mod to understand that?

[Why does one incorrect repo block every other repo from updating with Apt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401870/why-does-one-incorrect-repo-block-every-other-repo-from-updating-with-apt)

Comment: FYI:  I don't see any *mod* making comment or tagging a question on your linked, or [original](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401861/why-does-one-incorrect-repo-block-every-other-repo-from-updating-with-apt) question.  You can tell it's a *mod* by the *diamond* appearing after their name.  I only see user comments.

Comment: Related: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19944/1438484 - if you're sure that your question isn't specific to that version and is applicable to an on-topic version of Ubuntu (IMO your question is applicable to on-topic versions), then edit your original question removing mentions  of the version, and check the box that says it should be placed in the queue of questions to be reviewed for re-opening

Comment: @cocomac thank you, but what if it isnt reopened? I dont know about AskUbuntu, but the mods seem to be grossly absent on other SE sites. I have flagged several posts for moderation and never received any response.

Comment: What do you mean "never received any response"? Typically, you don't get a response - your flag is marked "helpful", because they took care of it. It's pretty rare to get a custom response to a flag. If all of your flags age away, then that's a different story. If the community votes to keep it closed, then they feel that it is off-topic. Honestly, I'm not sure what the rules/guidelines are for a general question about an unspecified release. That said, people can simply downvote because they think it isn't a useful question.

Comment: Honestly, this question was off-topic for more than one reason.  So even if the original closure reason has been resolved, it's still off topic because it's not a practical answerable question in the scope of our Q&A format.  The behavior you are describing is how apt works everywhere. There's no problem to be solved and there's no canonical answer to this question.

Comment: @Nmath so the person that just answered it with a technical answer is just spouting nonsense? ..I really dont get where your negativity is coming from.

Comment: It's a good answer and is essentially an extended version of "this is how it's designed to work" which multiple people told you in comments, of which you were unsatisfied.

Comment: @Nmath dude, you just contradicted yourself, so I cant debate/argue with you anymore.

Comment: OK well we can agree to disagree. In any case, you've got a very well composed answer that explains how the software is written.

Comment: @Nmath our scope does not require a problem to be solved, it only requires an on-topic question that can be answered. "Why does apt work this way" is on topic and answerable, the lack of a problem is irrelevant.

Answer (score 7):

Well, presumably the confusion here arose because the problem you ran into is happening because of your Ubuntu version, as pointed out in the comments - the problem is that there is no package for your Ubuntu version in the repository yet. This is a very common problem. We have a canonical post about it: [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file).

However, it's quite clear that you are asking *why* APT behaves in the way it does ([the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1401873/527764) makes this even clearer, as is often the case) and that the example from your system should be taken as an arbitrary example. This is not a *problem specific to a development version of Ubuntu* and so should not be closed for that reason.

Also, the question is not "opinion based" (once again - those who think it is may observe that it has been answered in a largely objective manner with reference to the source code). Also note that questions like "isn't x a security risk?" can usually receive good answers based on expertise.

Currently your question is not in the close vote queue any more and may not be closed. If it does get closed, comment here and we will reopen it.

In general if one feels that one's question has been wrongly closed one can:

- edit it to make it clearer that the close reason does not apply
- post on meta to ask for a review
- if one has enough reputation, come to [the Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat?_=4959438) chatroom and ask for help
- if one has enough reputation, vote to reopen the question

---

NB: while moderation, including close voting, is undertaken by the whole community, most people here understand "mods" to refer to [elected moderators](https://askubuntu.com/help/site-moderators) i.e. [this bunch](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators).

Comment: thank you. why is it a user has to fight to keep a legitimate question open? one that I would posit is objectively legitimate. There seems to be a shoot first and ask questions later mentality of users with moderation privileges. I have seen this so often, I will conjecture it is incentivized by the system. Somehow by points earning. I come here to help and be helped, not for points. I would very strongly support the mods revisiting whatever incentives this unproductive and energy wasting behavior.

Comment: btw, I have another post that was closed for basically the same reason, by the same gaggle of hecklers. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400470/kernel-module-not-getting-installed-after-upgrade Yes, it happened when I upgraded.. No, the question and the answer were not in any way related to an 'unsupported version'.

Comment: There are no incentives for closing questions. One does not gain any reputation for voting to close. It is unclear why many questions are wrongly closed.

Comment: @alchemy In a perfect world, you wouldn't have to fight. But... I do agree that people are too quick to close questions. Even when the version or even distro is fully irrelevant, the question of "what version of Ubuntu do you have" is asked, as if they just wanted it closed. I don't know why - flags don't add to rep (badges maybe?). "rationale"/"why" questions [tend to be closed](https://askubuntu.com/q/1384943/). IMO, we should have a Meta post about if they are OK. The policy about questions where the version is off-topic, but also irrelevant, is unclear to many users, which causes confusion

Comment: Your other question was closed as a bug report. In my view, only questions that are actually intended as bug reports (or feature requests) should be closed as such, but this particular close reason has long been overly broadly applied. I have been planning to post on meta about this, but I am not sure that people will agree with my stance. I need to develop my argument. Also, I need to go and post my brother's birthday present and buy groceries. Will return later!

Comment: That is good to know. It must just be the negativity brigade that like to prey on people looking for help. I know thats pretty cynical, but I'm finally coming to the conclusion that is what it is. In that case, removing visible downvoting like youtube has, and only allowing the actual mods to close a question seems very reasonable.

Comment: @cocomac thanks.. it seems like rationale/why questions often have a technical answer that is useful, regardless of the why answer, although sometimes that has a techical answer too.. really what is the harm in letting questions not be closed? are there server resources really cramped by basically text-only data?

Comment: @alchemy It isn't a concern of server resources. It is a concern if they are on-topic (and/or useful). But while I have an opinion, the comments here aren't the best place for that discussion. Instead, I suggest you make a Meta Ask Ubuntu question regarding if "rationale" questions are acceptable, so we can get a definative answer.

Comment: @Zanna yes, of course, take care of life! ..I cant respond to your mod comment on that post because posts are still locked, but while Apt update fails, Apt upgrade still proceeds.. I just tested that. The 'luckily' part was simply because the security repo is listed second in the sources.list file. If it were any further down, I would consider changing it.

Comment: that is interesting! I think more answers could be posted to your question about APT's behaviour

Comment: @cocomac please dont take this personally, as it is a HUGE frustration of mine on every SE site, which is pretty much my main, or at least first, website for any technical question or problem I have.. why? because human interactive conversation is so vastly more valuable than some single persons blog.. so the Meta question I would ask (and heres the dont take it personal part) is why in the expletive expletive expletive expletive expletive expletive expletive expletive expletiveexpletive expletive expletive expletive God's sake does it even matter what is off topic. Let people HELP EACH OTHER!

Comment: @alchemy This isn't obvious, and I can't find the Meta post for it at the moment. But... Stack Exchange isn't a forum. Nor is it a personal helpdesk. It is a large database of collective knowledge, and that is grouped into various sites. That is the core philosophy - a useful Q&A site, as a database of knowledge. If we could ignore what was on topic, it would fall into total chaos. SE isn't about getting your question answered, or about finding you a solution quickly - it is about creating a large database of helpful information. And if there were no rules, that wouldn't work.

Comment: @cocomac I completely disagree it would fall into chaos. Reddit works totally fine, it just doesnt have the same large pool of experts and I cant login using Google (which may actually be interrelated). Good content bubbles up with votes. Maybe some reigns on topics to science versus pop culture helps to keep the unconstructive crowd away (although there is SE politics), that would be fine with me (though it might not even need that). I think the real reason is server resources, which is why you have to pay Reddit to not have to click to wait and scroll down each page. Also, fine.. but the..

Comment: @cocomac ..pendulum has swung so far in the direction of stifling any slight little tiny possibility of a thing that might be off-topic, "oh-no", that it comes to where people have to fight just to post a legitimate asking for help. I say, open it up, and put limits in place only if server space is a problem. Those limits could very simply be by usefulness metric gauged by popular-ness. If no one cares, archive it. If it is unrelated to science, same thing. But otherwise for the love of God, like I said, let honest people just help each other. Lastly, is that chaos just a fear-based opinion?

Comment: @alchemy I respectfully disagree. I think that would cause too many issues. Regardless, that is just my opionion. If you disagree, which you may, then go to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) (the site for discussing things about the entire SE network), and make that request. Warning: some people may disagree with you, and I strongly urge you to read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953/) first. But, feel free to suggest that there if you think it will work better. Also, [voting is special on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188/).

Comment: point in case.. on my other post that was voted to be closed.. I got an answer that solved my problem.. *very* luckily within an hour, right before the post was closed.. how in the you know what does closing something that helped me solve a big problem that stopped me from having any audio and my firewall from working help anyone? The fact that it was answer so quickly and also closed so quickly should give anyone looking at those times an idea of the scale of how useful it is to leave questions that somehow might be off-topic (even though unquestionably science and help related) + the convers

Comment: @cocomac, thank you for that level-headed response. ..I would just ask again, has it ever even been tried.. (if not, its all speculation)

Comment: Uh... here on SE? AFAIK, it hasn't been. Other sites operate more like that (Quora for one). But I don't think it has ever been tried on Stack Exchange. Feel free to suggest that on Meta SE, though, if you think it would be beneficial/good, although note that people vote more on Meta, so questions tend to be either highly downvoted or highly upvoted. So note that Meta is more extreme. But, if you think it would be benifical, then suggest it!

Comment: @cocomac so that link says two things to me.. first, it implicates high-rep users, which I really think is a big part of the problem.. giving powers to crush others only incentivizes sadists (whether self-aware or not) to come, get rep, and be jerks. That is definitely the sense I have from using this site for more than a decade (so just leave those powers to mods which is their purpose and can be voted in/out).. Second, as stated, the bubble-up system does functionally help, and that may be all needed, with banning spammers, moving unrelated comments to the new chat.. IMO thats all that's it.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to go now, but [feel free to ping me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat), and I can respond in the morning. A few last thoughts... spammers are bad. They have to go. But the idea isn't that high-rep users are jerks. It is that they have to maintain quality for the site to not go down. If the hostilty is worth that is debatable. Also, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/16886597 (both of the top two answers are worth a read, even if you disagree). But feel free to ping me in chat to discuss more!

Comment: @cocomac the problem is now the 'senators' arent going to vote for 'term limits', so people like me end up suffering when Im just trying to get through a problem.. I've spent hours just defending a legit question, when I just, want, to, go, back, to, work.. and then the frustration builds up sooo high that I end up lashing out and writing long diatribes like this one, that are going to do nothing except maybe inform the boots on the ground experience of a couple of mods in AskUbuntu (that actually listen) and that's it.. but thanks for the warning.. im not sure if anything will help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135462/discussion-between-cocomac-and-alchemy).

Comment: recently I read every one of the candidates for moderation and specifically ordered them on their statement regarding stopping this nonsense.

Comment: This is still "on-topic" for this discussion, no?.. we are trying to figure out how to stop the bad behavior of the title at the source, or systematically. I would prefer that others see how frustrated this makes an honest user feel. Having an emotional outburst that is still logical seems like the only thing that makes any progress at all about this (again 'senators'). My only hope it I could convince a mod to convince another mod here on AskUbuntu (where the mods actually listen mostly) and that AskUbuntu could try some changes that have some vague hope of extending out to other SEs.

Comment: Interesting answer there https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/4240654.. more interesting is the top comment with votes maybe the highest ive seen on a comment, and that thread is locked and was posted in 2014. ..To me, it is a segment of group 3 that uses their mod-like priveleges to make the experience of group 5 miserable. And should be stopped, by just taking away the powers they abuse. Even if it is on a complaint based basis. 3 of the ones trying to stifle me were pattern offenders on my last closed question.

Comment: @cocomac I think long comment discussions are okay on meta - meta is here for discussion after all :)

Comment: @alchemy Your second post has not been closed as such, all that has happened is that activity was 'frozen' (Locked) for a period of 24 hours. I put this in place as things were becoming a little too heated and the search for a good question and answer set was becoming lost in some pretty tense disputation. The Lock will expire in 17 hours from now, hopefully leaving a question and answer pair that will be useful for other users as well as yourself. See here for 'Locking': https://askubuntu.com/help/locked-posts

Comment: @andrew.46 thanks. I have some comments surrounding that, but will wait until I have time to compose them better. I appreciate the moderation.

Comment: it seems a lot of people here like to argue until there logical inconsistencies are pointed out. I'm thinking of starting a public list of users that simply like to argue. it would be publically appendable with cited instances. I think this would also really help the mods do their jobs more efficiently (in fact, I think they need this tool), because it seems the way SE works is to incentivize users to gain power to shape the site how they desire, by farming the work of mods to normal users. Then the mods come in as cleanup crew, which is never better than 'community policing'. cynical but real

Comment: this might build momentum or at least clarity of the problem, that certain high rep users abuse their privileges in a pattern to make the sites more toxic which has been pointed out numerous times. One answer is to take away those privileges. Another is to hone in on those that abuse them regularly. The elected mods can decide what constitutes abuse not on high-rep popularity, but on site functioning metrics, which like the over-closing problem can be subjectively obtained by collective consensus.

Comment: @andrew.46 while I hope I've made enough of a statement already.. for the future.. who has the power to change what abilities users have.. is that a central SE thing, or does each site get to decide?

Comment: @alchemy Ask Ubuntu has a relationship with Stack Exchange and this relationship is mediated through Community Managers. But before making that sort of approach you would be better to engage a little more with the Ask Ubuntu community. Meta can be useful, as you have found, but have a look at Chat where you can meet both mods and other users. The community normally works things out and if not there are the moderators. It is usually a robust and well working system. See you in Chat?

Comment: I certainly could have used a more helpful tone with your question. At the time, my understanding of both your original post and your repost was that your intention was to start a discussion, or to express dissatisfaction with how apt works. When reading clarifications from comments, it reinforced my belief that this was the kind of response you were looking for. These are the reasons I voted to close. When you reposted the same exact thing after the first was closed, I saw it as circumventing moderation. So I apologize that I was prejudiced by this interpretation of your question

Comment: I disagree wholeheartedly that "reddit works totally fine" doing the same thing that Stack Exchange and Ask Ubuntu are set out to do. I think it's important that we stay focused as being a helpful and *factual* source of information, and not a free-for-all for open discussions, opinions, grievances about software, etc. That kind of stuff drowns out helpful content and a site filled with opinion-based responses in particular make it difficult to discern factual information. The community here does a good job fact-checking, which cannot be said for reddit where anything goes.

Comment: And to your points about behaviors of moderators and community, many of us have signed and believe in the code of conduct rooted in collaboration and respect and common goals. We do not have to agree with each other about the scope of the site. That's why meta exists. Tone and intent are difficult in writing in the first place and this is especially true when in a disagreement. With that in mind, I'd rethink your approach of calling high rep users "toxic" and making lists and callouts. We could all do better to remember that mutual respect and collaboration even when we disagree